# Can chess moves be patented?

Tags: patentability

I've invented a new play in chess that allows me to place my opponent in checkmate after 15 moves.

Would I be able to get a patent on this? What are the requirements for patenting something like this?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps someone can cite the actual test-for-patentability this fails, but methods can only be patented as long they produces some concrete, useful, and tangible result. Winning a chess game would not seem to qualify.

Beyond that, chess moves used in tournaments fill huge databases for study. It does not seem likely your combination of moves (or some significant part) has not produced *prior art* in its 1500 year history, or at least the last 200-some-odd years of modern, competitive play.

Comment: Ok, I am agree.